# SQL Server 2012 and .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have a server which configured for SQL Server 2008 R2 and ASP.NET 4.0.

The hosting company won't support .Net Framework 4.5 and SQL Server 2012 and latest Entity Framework.

I have created my website with .Net Framework 4.5 and latest Entity Framework 5. How can I change the publish settings to old server execute that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Target Framework for your website.In Visual Studio (with your website project selected) go to Project  >  Settings. Change Target Framework from .Net Framework 4.5 to .Net 4. Then rebuild all and test your app.

If it's all working OK you can then publish to your web host as normal.

Comment: @Parkhid: toss out EF 5, re-install EF 4.x using NuGet, recompile your app

Comment: You can use EF5 with .Net 4.0. As @marc_s suggests you can use the NuGet tool to install the EF package http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/)

Answer (score 2):

Change the Target Framework of the Website, In Solution Explorer right click the Website select 'Properties'. In the dialog that appears select Application now change the Target Framework to 4.0 and Publish.

Answer (score 0):

The above 2 answers are correct.  Additionally, many hosting companies do not support the MVC or EF dll's of any version. There is any easy work around to this.  As long as you can get your code to compile in Visual Studio 2010 using .NEt 4.0, right click on your project and click 'Add Deployable Deployable Dependencies'. Check the boxes for the dll's groups you will need and they will be added to your project so they can be deployed with your website.

Answer (score 0):

When installing EF5 from Nuget it will install EntityFramework.dll assembly version 5.0.0.0. if your app is targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or EntityFramework.dll assembly version 4.4.0.0 if your app is targeting .NET Framework 4. The difference between these is that EF5 for .NET Framework 4 is scoped down to what is supported by the core assembly (System.Data.Entity.dll) that is a part of .NET Framework (most notably on .NET Framework 4 you will get no enums, spatial types etc.). If you change the target after installing EntityFramework then you most likely need to uninstall what you have and install again to get the right version of the EntityFramework.dll.

Answer (score 0):

you just create a new project in framework 4 and add existing items from the right click in solution in project